# How to repurpose a variable creation via textarea input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my app, I am using the text input a user submits to set their username. Another functionality we now need is to be able to also get an email later on and store that as a variable. I've tried a couple different ideas to get it to work, some of these are:

1. appending the input back in
2. hiding the input on first creation, then showing when needed
3. creating a new input when needed

But whatever I seem to try, it always sets my username variable, then automatically sends the follow up message. The user flow should be:

> Bot says hello / asks for a name
>
> User enters name -- sets as username var
>
> Bot says hello + username, then asks for email
>
> User enters email -- sets as email var

My problem persists on step 4, where I try to set the email variable. Pretty much anything that is entered into said input is considered a username.

---

**My Code**

Getting username (called on load)

```
function get_username(){
    send_msg("Hello I'm Mumbles, the Help Bot", function(){
    send_msg("Who am I speaking with today?")
  });
}
```

Setting username variable

```
function ai(msg){
    if (username.length < 3){
    username = msg;
        send_msg('Nice to meet you '+username+'.', function(){
    send_msg("One more thing, could you enter your email below?")
    });
  }
}
```

Update Prev State on Click

```
$('#sendMsg').click(function(){
        var userName = "<span class='username'> Me: </span>";
        var newMsg = $('#message').val();

        $('#message').val('');

        var prevState = $('#conversation').html();
        if (prevState.length > 3){
            prevState = prevState + '<br />';
        }
        $('#conversation').html(prevState + userName + newMsg);

        ai(newMsg);
            $('#conversation').scrollTop($('#conversation').prop('scrollHeight'));

    });
```

---

**Code related to asking for an email**

```
} else if (b_val == "my_practicum") {
      send_msg("What is the email address you submitted your practicum with? By having this we can give you a status update!" , function() {
            $("#message").show();
            $('button.message-tools').val('email_submitted');
  $("#sendMsg").click(function() {
    var email = msg;
    console.log(email);

  });
      });
    }
```

---

To see a bare-mininum example of my code, check out **[this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x7e0dbzc/1/)**.

To see the version with my attempt at trying to capture email, check out **[this fiddle](https://codepen.io/TyStelmach/pen/awOyGE)**.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your examples do not seem to operate the way you describe. Not being prompted for email.

Comment: @Twisty sorry, I must have been editing it, if you take a look here, it will prompt you.https://jsfiddle.net/x7e0dbzc/3/

Comment: Ok, that works. This seems like more an issue in your stateful logic. Is the bot sending a message, prompting for an answer, or confirming something? When prompting for an answer, you may need to defer until the user has entered a response. I suspect that the variable isn't updated at the right time, so the old value is passed back before the new value is collected.

Comment: I basically want it to work the same way as the username function works, bot asks for value, you type it and hit enter and then the bot can refer back to it because it was updated/saved as a variable

Comment: Start looking into it here: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/pn57okeo/1/ using Deferred objects

Comment: Here is a way to sort of hack it: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/pn57okeo/2/ not something I like.

Comment: @Twisty never even thought to do it that way, I ended up just using a conditional in the on click, then checking if the var existed to determine which one to update. For a proof of concept, it will work. I think if we want to continue on this we'll rebuild using a nice object/variable management.

Thanks!